# Google MX telnet returns 250 OK for invalid email addresses

Tags: email, telnet

We are trying to figure out how to reduce the amount of bounces for our email platform and, one of the solutions we've found on the internet is to, via telnet, verify if the email exists.

So, for this example, we connect to the MX:

`telnet alt4.aspmx.l.google.com 25`

We start the communication:

`helo hi`

And, for every email we try (valid and invalid ones), we always receive the same response:

```
mail from: <fsafsaffsf@FasgagaoaSFasfas.co>
250 2.1.0 OK d8si998940wrc.143 - gsmtp
```

Are they doing this to prevent maybe a possible listing of valid emails?

What is the best way to verify if an email is valid before sending an email to it? We need this because our clients often uploads a spreadsheet with customer emails and always one or two of them are mistyped.

Thanks.

Comment: `250 Requested mail action okay, completed.` Probably prior to user account delivery attempted.

Answer (score 0):

For a given recipient email address, you can:

- extract its domain name (everything after `@`)
- query DNS for the MX record(s) of that domain
- for each specified server, connect and issue a `VRFY` command (see [RFC 5321 Section 3.5](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5321#section-3.5)), asking the server to verify the email address.
- stop when you get a success reply.

However, SMTP servers are not required to implement `VRFY`.  The simpler solution would be to just send the email normally, and then handle any errors from the `RCPT TO` command, and also handle the possibility that you simply can't always detect delivery errors in real time.  If the email has to be relayed across servers, it might not fail on the server you use for sending, it may not fail until it is relayed to another server after you have already ended your SMTP session. In which case, the only way to detect delivery errors is to monitor your inbound mailbox for delivery failure emails being sent back to you.